# File Picker Module Showing Blank Squares (Image Holders) During Pic Selection

Tags: android

Points to note:

1. This was working on real device before, now it's just showing blank images when trying to select images using the file picker. (using Android 10)
2. On emulator it works just fine

My Activity:

```
    private void filePicker(){

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityImage_Cloud.this, ImagePickActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra(IS_NEED_CAMERA, true);
    intent1.putExtra(Constant.MAX_NUMBER, 30);
    intent1.putExtra(IS_NEED_FOLDER_LIST, true);
    startActivityForResult(intent1, Constant.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constant.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<ImageFile> list = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constant.RESULT_PICK_IMAGE);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (ImageFile file : list) {
                    String path = file.getPath();
                    builder.append(path + "\n");

                    arrListStr_FileToUpload.add(path);
                    stringArr_FileToUpload = new String[arrListStr_FileToUpload.size()];
                    stringArr_FileToUpload = arrListStr_FileToUpload.toArray(stringArr_FileToUpload);
                }

                ftp_UploadFiles();
            }
    }
}
```

I have declared Read and Write permissions in Mainfest and are checking permissions at runtime of
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Link to file picker module:

```
    https://www.dropbox.com/s/jlukqfydegnyd3c/filepicker.rar?dl=0
```

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a better image picker, rather than a random RAR from a random Dropbox location. [There are dozens to choose from](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?sort=created).

Comment: `String path = file.getPath();` Show some examples of values for path.

Comment: @CommonsWare will have a look at your the image picker from your link, Im the one who uploaded the filepicker onto dropbox

Comment: @blackapps: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20201023_114451.jpg

Comment: So you can pick files and get their paths. Then what is the problem? If you see blank images in the file picker then post code of the file picker. I dont understand why you posted irrelevant code. I do not understand your problem i think. As you did not tell.

Comment: @blackapps - I have added screenshots, note that on real device the selection images are blank but on emulator I can see the images, the filepicker code is a multi file class which i uploaded on the dropbox link.

Comment: I will believe that you see those squares. But i have no idea what you are doing there, how you obtained the paths,  and i will not get that code from dropbox . If you have problems with you picker you should post the code of the picker. If you have problems with the file paths delivered by your picker then tell so. The path you mentioned looks ok. But as you did not tell what happens if you try to use/upload that path.. yes.. then what is the problem? Is your problem only those squares? Or using the obtained path too? Reread your post please. You are not telling that.

Comment: `when trying to select images using the file picker. ` Pretty strange that you are talking about 'the file picker' instead of first telling that you deleveloped  your own file picker. Very confusing.